# NestedScrollView smooth scroll to the top and to a view inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

First I need to scroll my `NestedScrollView` to the top, but `smoothScrollTo(0, 0)` doesn't work for me (page just jumping a bit). Second I wonder how can I scroll to a certain view inside my `NestedScrollView`. API 27, Support 27.0.2.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/PageBackground"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/indent_page_bottom">

                ...

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: for others, this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083678/nestedscrollviews-smoothscrollto-behaves-weird

Answer (score 2):

Try using `fling` to achieve smooth scrolling :

```
nestedScrollView.fling(0);
nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a `nestedscrollview`and inside it there is `recyclerview`. I tried `smoothScrollTo(0, nsv_main.top)`. Didn't work. I gave an id to `nestedscrollview` like below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsv_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/PageBackground"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/indent_page_bottom">

        ...

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and gave `nsv_main.scrollY = 0` in my click event. It worked, even though its not a smooth scroll.

Comment: nsv_main.scrollY = 0 : Didn't work for me.
I have a ConstraintLayout inside a NestedScrollView which has a recyclerView height set to wrap_content.